# How to fix order of Django migrations?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, migration, database-migration

I have several apps in my Django 2.0.2 project. One of the apps (`app_one`) has a migration that depends on migrations from the other app (`app_two`) being installed. It is initial migration of `app_one` and it looks like this:

```
def import_data(apps, schema_editor):
    schema_model = apps.get_model('app_two', 'Model')
    # do import

def drop_data(apps, schema_editor):
    schema_model = apps.get_model('app_two', 'Model')
    # undo import

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app_two', '0005_auto_20180127_2155')
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(
            import_data, 
            reverse_code=drop_data
    )
]
```

Currently in order to install the database I need to `manage.py migrate app_two` and only after that do `manage.py migrate`, because otherwise I get an error on this migration that relation `Model` from `app_two` does not exist. Also I'm unable to run tests `manage.py test` normally due to the same error. It seems that Django ignores dependency in this migration for some reason. How do I fix that?

Comment: what version of django are you using?

Comment: @BrianOcampo, 2.0.2. Added version to the question.

Comment: Add the models code and project settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDK wat's happening, but today I made some changes to migrations like adding `run_before` and the issue was gone. ***BUT! I rolled all changes back, droped all the related databases and the bug didn't came back.*** The code is literally the same as it was when I posted the question...

Answer (score 3):

Check out the docs about ordering your migrations:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/writing-migrations/#controlling-the-order-of-migrations

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Django documentation regarding the configuration variable MIGRATION_MODULES.

Link to doc:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIGRATION_MODULES

Comment: Could you explain a bit more of what is wrong with my migration and how `MIGRATION_MODULES` could help.